# What are some techniques for communicating data distributions to unsophisticated users?

Tags: mean, standard-deviation, descriptive-statistics, communication

In my scenario, students are grouped into classes and each student has a performance metric. I want to be able to show teachers and principals a list of classes, along with an aggregate performance metric for each class.

I don't want to show the mean, because one very high or low performing student skews this. I don't want to show the median, because this basically discards the very high or low performing students entirely, and I want to capture the contribution of these students.

More correct would probably be to show a visualization of the mean with standard deviation, but this would be too sophisticated for many of my users, and it's not a single number that could be used, for instance, to sort the list by "performance".

Is there a better technique for computing aggregate performance into one number that somehow captures the variance of the data set?

Answer (score 1):

I am actually a student and in my experience the best visualization for a scenario like this could actually be boxplots. Using these will show the the different quartiles for each class as well as outliers. I would suggest that you create a grid with all the boxplots plotted next to one another. In this way it will be easy to show teachers and parents how different classes performed relative to one another.

Comment: That might work, although I think boxplots are a bit hard on the brain and I'm not sure my audience would find them intuitive.

Comment: The only other option that I can think of are histograms, but I guess those might also not be so intuitive as you would like?